# Creating excel and word files alternatives

Tags: javascript, meteor, ms-word

Im being digging a little bit about the possibility of creating `excel` and `word` data using `METEOR` javascript framework does anybody has an idea how this could be achieved?? Any recommendation? I haven't found nothing about it, and I think I should come with some random solution the thing is that I have to use javascript for this I guess.

I know it is too early to request this kind of stuff in the meteor community but if somebody have an idea how to implementing this using only javascript I would glad to hear about it...

I'm looking some similar libraries as http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

UPDATE ---

After 1 year using meteor, I think that this is not at all a concern of the meteor framework and shouldn't be, the solution relay more from a javascript perspective, there are some package in `npm` to achieve this. And you can import them inside meteor without problems.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me. What makes you think Meteor can create Excel and Word data in the first place? What kind of Javascript are you talking about here, serverside or browserside?

Comment: I know he cant, but in some point should be able to do it as php, asp.net or any othe framework do it isnt?

Comment: Or how do you think you should be able to export data for your users in excel,pdf or word formats if you chose meteor as you framework in the future?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a core job for an application Framework. But  I can't say, I don't know the product at all. Anyway - so you want to create Word documents in JavaScript? Googling `javascript create word document` (for example) gives me some results, are they not useful?

Comment: Yes I think it does, thanks man. http://parall.ax/products/jspdf# as example

Comment: The most interesting thing i found about this is this https://github.com/edi9999/docxtemplater

Answer (score 0):

This is still a great question! [Officegen](https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen) does the job:

```
var officegen = require('officegen');

var myDoc = officegen('<type>');

// Supported types:
// 'pptx' or 'ppsx' - Microsoft Powerpoint based document.
// 'docx' - Microsoft Word based document.
// 'xlsx' - Microsoft Excel based document.
```